# Automatically populate Cases in a Switch statement based on the values in an enum

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a quick way to fill the cases in a `switch` statement in Xcode?  I figure if an `enum` value has 6 possible cases, all 6 cases could easily be pre-populated based on the `typedef`.

Comment: You'd think/hope so, given that you get a warning if you miss one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in Xcode by installing a plug-in called SCXcodeSwitchExpander:

https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCXcodeSwitchExpander

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but no. You can cut and paste, but that's about it.